# Mouse configurations not staying when using RemoteApps

Tags: group-policy, rdp, remoteapp, mouse, user-settings

I have some clients who need to use a larger mouse curser. However, when they use the RemoteApps we published for them, the configuration is not staying in place.

I thought maybe if I created a GPO to force the configuration that would work. It does not. It works when you RDP into a desktop but not when using a RemoteApp.

The GPO changes the users' registry to the desired mouse settings, yet it is not sticking in RemoteApps.

Also, this is for any published RemoteApp, we publish Windows File Explorer for them and that also reverts the mouse configuration back to Windows' default

Is there so configuration setting somewhere to control how a mouse looks in a RemoteApp specifically or something like that?